# falling words not giving expected results

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make this GUI where there are these words that fall from the top of the screen and I have the following code in my constructor, where the word moves by one unit every 100 milliseconds. However, when I run the program the word appears at 400 once I start and not at the top of the screen. I suppose that there is a specific method that could update my y value in continuous time? Thanks!

```
while(y <= 400){
      y++;
      repaint();
      try {
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
      }  catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Painting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
}
```

Comment: With what value does `y` start? It's kind of missing in your snippet.

Comment: i started with y=20, it's kind of arbitrary

Comment: _Don't_ sleep on the EDT; _do_ see [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

sleeping your thread isn't the best practice to take the desired result, use [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) instead:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() { //100 is the delay time between each interval
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
            y ++;
            if (y > 400) {
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
```